# Applying timestamp to dynamic row upon change event

Tags: excel, vba

**Goal:**

I would like to have a date/time stamp put into one column beyond the last column in the row being changed, based on a change event.  The cell's value when selected is to be compared to that same cell's value when it is no longer the target.

**Current Code:**

*Within the Sheet1 View Code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'MsgBox "Now: " & Now()

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim k As String
Dim LC As Long

i = Target.Row
j = Target.Column
k = Target.Value
LC = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

If Not Cells(i, j).Value = k Then
    Cells(i, LC + 1).Formula = Format(Now(), "yyyyMMddhhmmss")
End If

End Sub
```

**Problem:**

After trying to run this code, I cannot get any output.  I tested using MsgBox "Now: "&now(), which does show me that the change event code is in the correct place (I commented that out, but it was how I checked what *should* have appeared.

I thought that, by defining i, j, and k, outside of the If statement that I could save those values and compare values from selection compared to when not selected.

**Question:**

Is the way I am setting this code up inappropriate, and if so how would I correct this to be more appropriate?  This is my first time playing with change events.

Edit1:  Adding more specifics to goal, considering comment by @ScottCraner

Comment: you testing whether the target cell or cell that changed is not equal to the value that is in it.  This will always return false as the target cell will always equal the target cell value.  One more note, once you figure out what you actually want to test, you will need to put in a `application.EnableEvents = False` before making changes and `application.EnableEvents = True` after so it does not go into a loop that will fill the row with dates till you run out of columns.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for that.  I didn't even think about turning events off there (foolish am I).  I am looking to make sure that my initially selected cell is still the same when I exit that cell, assuming I use down arrow and cross over some cells.

Comment: The worksheet_change event will not fire unless a cell value is changed not the selection.  After the change the Range variable Target has all the attributes of the cell that changed, including its new value not the old.  The old is gone.

Comment: @ScottCraner ...and again, thank you.  I feel like these are things I should know from what I've read so far, however this is exactly what I need to hear so I can learn to use this moving forward.

Comment: @Cyril according to your edited post, you want to keep the previous value of the cell being modified now and compare the 2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comments you want:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'MsgBox "Now: " & Now()

Dim i As Long

Dim LC As Long

i = Target.Row
LC = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells(i, LC + 1).Formula = Format(Now(), "yyyyMMddhhmmss")
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: beat me by 56 seconds , +1. You could get rid of `i` as well

Comment: Thanks for following through with me on this.  I appear to have missed the  mark on how the change event was triggered.  Much appreciated.  Will give @ShaiRado a +1 so he gets something out of his time, as you two mirrored!

Comment: @ShaiRado yes, but meh. Typing the extra i's is less then typing `Target.Row` twice.  And by that logic one could do it without the LC also.

Comment: @ScottCraner you're right. I usually keep it, I like to have shorter and more readable code lines

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LC As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False

LC = Cells(Target.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Cells(Target.Row, LC + 1).Formula = Format(Now(), "yyyyMMddhhmmss")

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```